# Internet speed is reduced when connected to Aipods and bluetooth devices

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have tested my macbook air M1 with three different situations.

Case 1: AirPods,Bluetooth keyboard and mouse connected,

- Speed test results Download: 4.67 mbps Upload: 16.75 mbps

Case 2: Bluetooth keyboard and mouse connected,

- Speed test results Download: 12.99 mbps Upload: 22.41 mbps

Case 3: Bluetooth off

- Speed test results Download: 34.45 mbps Upload: 47.58 mbps[image]

Comment: There is no question here?  What are you looking for?